# How to close the virtual keyboard from a Jetpack Compose TextField?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-input-method, android-compose-textfield

I'm using the Jetpack Compose `TextField` and I want to close the virtual keyboard when the user press the the action button (`imeActionPerformed` parameter).

```
val text = +state { "" }
TextField(
    value = text.value,
    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
    imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
    onImeActionPerformed = { 
        // TODO Close the virtual keyboard here <<<
    }
    onValueChange = { s -> text.value = s }
)
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Starting from compose [`1.0.0-alpha12`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-animation?authuser=1#1.0.0-alpha12) (and still valid in compose `1.6.4`) the `onImeActionPerformed` is deprecated and suggested approach is to use `keyboardActions` with combination of `keyboardOptions`:

```
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = ...,
        onValueChange = ...,
        label = ...,
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { focusManager.clearFocus() }),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(imeAction = ImeAction.Done, keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password),
    )
```

`focusManager.clearFocus()` will take care of dismissing the soft keyboard.

Comment: This is not working inside an `AlertDialog`. Nothing I have tried, `SoftwareKeyboardController`, `FocusManager`, nor `FocusRequester` work in a dialog. Any ideas?

Comment: @shelll Try to initialize FocusManager inside the dialog. In my case it worked.

Comment: @Drogheda yes, this is it! Thanks! Maybe post it as a separate answer too.

Comment: @shelll Did you get any solution for this on dialog? I am facing the same issue with dialog.

Comment: @fargath yes, the comment above, from Drogheda solved it!

Answer (score 255):

You can use the [**`LocalSoftwareKeyboardController`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/LocalSoftwareKeyboardController) class to control the current software keyboard and then use the **`hide`** method:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("Text")) }
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
        },
        label = { Text("Label") },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onDone = {keyboardController?.hide()})
)
```

This solution closes the keyboard **without removing the focus** from the current `TextField`.

Just to highlight the difference with:

```
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
focusManager.clearFocus()
```

This code closes the keyboard **removing the focus** from the `TextField`.

Comment: What are the differences between this and the focusManager approach (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66259111/2911458)? When should we use each?

Comment: @stkent this solution only hides the keyboard. The other solution also removes the focus from the current TextField (the cursor is still showing, it might still be highlighted, etc.)

Comment: When choosing between both solutions please also watch ux-continuity: The default-behavior: swiping back once hides the keyboard, and second swipe clears the focus.

Comment: @stkent for additional details, see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/68650009/12871582

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti How can I set up a TextField to **never invoking** the virtual keyboard at all? [Click on here to go to that question of mine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71535062/how-to-disable-showing-the-virtual-keyboard-when-tapping-on-a-textfield)

Comment: It's funny also sad that `LocalSoftwareKeyboardController` is Experimental since 2020!

Answer (score 25):

In `1.0.0` you can either use `SoftwareKeyboardController` or `FocusManager` to do this.

This answer focuses on their differences.

---

### Setup:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("")}

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { /* TODO */ }),
)
```

[image: setup]

---

### SoftwareKeyboardController:

Based on `@Gabriele Mariottis` answer.

```
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

// TODO =
keyboardController?.hide()
```

This only closes the keyboard, but does *NOT* clear the focus from any focused TextField (note the cursor & thick underline).

[image: Using Keyboard Controller]

---

### FocusManager:

Based on `@azizbekians` answer.

```
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

// TODO =
focusManager.clearFocus()
```

[image: Using Focus Manager]

This closes the keyboard AND clears the focus from the TextField.

Answer (score 11):

### Hiding the keyboard on button click

To add with [Gabriele Mariotti's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63696027/3819934), if you want to hide the keyboard conditionally, say after a button click, use this:

```
keyboardController?.hide()
```

For example, hide the keyboard after clicking the Add button:

```
var newWord by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

// Setup the text field with keyboard as provided by Gabriele Mariotti

...

Button(
        modifier = Modifier
                .height(56.dp),
        onClick = {
                if (!newWord.trim().isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        wordViewModel.onAddWord(newWord.trim())
                        newWord = ""
                        keyboardController?.hide()
                }
        ...
```

Comment: How can we SHOW the keyboard when we click the button? (keyboardController?.show() isn't working in this case)

Answer (score 5):

**There are two scenarios**

#### Scenario 1 - A TextField in an AlertDialog

**Make sure to initialize the `keyboard controller` or `focus manager` inside the `Dialog content scope`**

**(Dialog has its own keyboard controller)**

```
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = {
       // on dismiss
    }
) {
   // initialise the keyboard controller and focus Manager inside the content scope
   val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
   val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
}
```

hide the keyboard

```
keyboardController?.hide()
focusManager.clear()
```

---

##### Edge case - Dismiss the dialog and hide the keyboard

**There might be a keyboard flickering (keyboard hide and show quickly) issue when dismissing the dialog and keyboard at the same time.**

Try to hide the keyboard first then trigger the dismiss dialog event with a delay

```
Dialog() {
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    Button(onClick = {
       keyboardController?.hide()
       focusManager.clear()

       // notify the view model to dismiss the dialog

       viewModel.onNegativeButtonClicked()
    })
}
```

Inside the ViewModel

```
ViewModel {
    
  fun onNegativeButtonClicked() {

     // trigger dismissDialog event with delay
  }

}
```

---

#### Scenario 2 - TextField only (no dialog)

```
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    label = { Text("Label") },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = {
            keyboardController?.hide()
            // do something here
        }
    )
)
```

or you can just use `keyboardController` `focusManager` to hide the keyboard inside the click event

```
Button(onClick = {
    keyboardController?.hide()
})
```

Comment: "Make sure to initialize the keyboard controller or focus manager inside the Dialog scope (Dialog has its own keyboard controller)" thank you, I wasted an hour on this.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit after alpha-12 release:**
See @azizbekian response.

**Pre-alpha-12 response**

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-set-visibility-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1) :)

```
fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
    val imm: InputMethodManager = activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    var view = activity.currentFocus
    if (view == null) {
        view = View(activity)
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

I just need to call the function above from my component:

```
// getting the context
val context = +ambient(ContextAmbient)

// textfield state
val text = +state { "" }

TextField(
    value = text.value,
    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
    imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
    onImeActionPerformed = { 
        if (imeAction == ImeAction.Done) {
            hideKeyboard(context as Activity)
        }
    }
    onValueChange = { s -> text.value = s }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is **Modifer extension** to hide keyboard:

```
fun Modifier.hideKeyboardOnOutsideClick(): Modifier = composed {
    val controller = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    this then Modifier.noRippleClickable {
         controller?.hide()
    }
}
```

To avoid a ripple effect on the background use this extension:

```
fun Modifier.noRippleClickable(onClick: () -> Unit): Modifier = composed {
    this then Modifier.clickable(
         indication = null,
         interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
         onClick = onClick
    )
}
```

Usage:

```
setContent {
    // Main Container with keyboard hiding behavior
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .hideKeyboardOnOutsideClick()
    ) {
        // Your app's content here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to shut him down in the CoreTextField,use TextInputService to control the switch

```
val focus = LocalTextInputService.current
var text by remember{ mutableStateOf("")}
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(imeAction = ImeAction.Done, keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { focus?.hideSoftwareKeyboard() }),
    singleLine = true
)
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: Even this is not working in an `AlertDialog`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha02'

**Text Field With Hide Keyboard On Ime Action**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun TextFieldWithHideKeyboardOnImeAction() {
        val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
        var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        TextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = { text = it },
            label = { Text("Label") },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onDone = {
                    keyboardController?.hide()
                    // do something here
                }
            )
        )
    }
```

[image: Text Field With Hide Keyboard On Ime Action]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can add the following code to your text field:

...
singleLine = true,

By doing this, the Enter button will be converted to a Done button and the keyboard will be closed when clicked on.

sample code:

```
TextField(
                    value = myUserTyped,
                    singleLine = true,
```